# What is the eta-rule for nat?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

As far as I am aware of, the beta-rule of the natural numbers type `nat` states that (please correct me if I am wrong)

1. `natrec 0 t0 (lambda i ti. ts) := t0`
2. `natrec (succ k) t0 (lambda i ti. ts) := (fun i ti. ts)`

But what does the eta-rule says? I wonder how the following formulation is correct / accurate / complete

`natrec n 0 (lambda i ti. s i) := n`

Comment: You may want to have a look at papers on eta rules for coproducts. e.g. [Lindley's Extensional Rewriting with Sums](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-73228-0_19)

Answer (score 6):

I do not understand your notation, but the $\beta$-rule is not right (because you write down abstractions). It is:
\begin{align*}
\mathtt{natrec} \; 0 \; x \; f &= x \\
\mathtt{natrec} \; (\mathtt{succ}\;n) \; x \; f &= f \; n \; (\mathtt{natrec} \; n \; x \; f)
\end{align*}
where $x$ and $f$ are arbitrary (well-typed) terms. (Beware: not every term of a function type is of the form $\lambda x . e$!)

You can read $\beta$ rules as saying what happens when you apply a destructor to a constructor (for instance $\mathtt{fst} (a, b) = a$). An $\eta$-rule says what happens when you destruct a thing and then put it back together (for instance $u = (\mathtt{fst}\;u, \mathtt{snd}\;u)$.

We take numbers apart with $\mathtt{natrec}$ and put them together with $0$ and $\mathtt{succ}$, so the $\eta$-rule would be:
$$\mathtt{natrec} \; n \; 0 \; (\lambda \; x\; m \,.\, \mathtt{succ}\; m) = n.$$

Comment: Can you give an example of your "beware" comment? I was not aware of this, and can't come up with any example.

Comment: Sure: `(λ x . x) (λ y . y)` is an application and a function. It is true that it is *equal* to a $\lambda$-abstraction, but it itself is not one.

Comment: Ah. I automatically assumed we were considering expressions in normal form. You're absolutely right though

Comment: When stating inference rules, unless we're doing something very strange, we must consider all expressions.